# Operation that Turns Powers into Products Like How Logarithms Turn Products into Sums

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, power-towers

$$
\newcommand{\pow}{\mathop{\vcenter{\huge{\text{E}}}}\limits}
$$

The $\sum$ operator can be defined recursively as
$$
\sum_{i = a}^b f(i) = f(a) + \sum_{i = a + 1}^b f(i).
$$

Likewise, the $\prod$ operator can be defined as
$$
\prod_{i = a}^b f(i) = f(a) \prod_{i = a + 1}^b f(i).
$$

One can define an operator $\pow$ via
$$
\pow_{i = a}^b f(i) = f(a)^{\pow_{i = a + 1}^b f(i)}.
$$

Logarithms have a well-known property of being able to turn products into sums
$$
\log \prod = \sum \log
$$
which is actually what majorly prompted their study in the first place.

Is there analogous function $\psi$ that turns powers into products
$$
\psi \pow = \prod \psi?
$$

I imagine that $\phi$ is either the super-logarithm or at the very least closely related to it, but I have not been able to verify this property for myself (I find it hard to wrap my mind around tetration).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only such functions are constants, essentially because multiplication is commutative while exponentiation is not: for any $x$,
$$
\psi(x) = \psi(x^1) = \psi(x)\psi(1) = \psi(1)\psi(x) = \psi(1^x) = \psi(1).
$$
Indeed this shows that the only two possible constant functions are $\psi(x)=1$ and $\psi(x)=0$.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I just realized that for the most part, you cannot turn a noncommutative function into a commutative one with an operator because $\phi(a^b) = \phi(a)\phi(b) = \phi(b^a)$ in the case of this function.